# Cannot install Renpy in Ubuntu 22.04... subprocess returned an error code (1)

Tags: command-line, apt, software-installation

Did the following:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

... normal messages, no problem

```
$ sudo apt-get -y install renpy
```

... normal messages, no problem, until...

```
Setting up renpy (7.3.5+dfsg-2)... File "/usr/share/games/renpy/launcher/game/gui7/code.py", line 283 
l=re.sub(ur'_\((".*?\")\)', replace, l)
SyntaxError: invalid syntax.
dpkg: error processing package renpy (--configure):
installed renpy package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1. 
Errors were encountered while processing: renpy. E:subprocess /usr/bin/dpkg returned error code (1).
```

Note: The dpkg mention might be a fault extra typing made that is not in the memory of the terminal, so I cannot give more details.

The result is that I could not install renpy what is all I want. If I repeat the sequence the error persists. What to do to fix this?

Comment: This sounds like a bug that you should report against the renpy package - see for example [Porting Code to Python 3 with 2to3: Unicode string literals](https://diveintopython3.net/porting-code-to-python-3-with-2to3.html#unicodeliteral)

Answer (score 0):

I followed the suggestion made by Thomas Ward and went to Ren’py site for advise. For my surprise, I learned that the last version of renpy is version 8.0.3, and the previous one was 7.5.3, far from the 7.3.5 that is the one that came automatically from the repository after the ‘sudo apt-get -y install renpy’ that was recommended in several places to install renpy for Ubuntu 22.04.

Anyway, I got and installed the last version according to the procedure recommended by Ren’py and now I can run renpy .exe or .sh files, and even more, I got a Launcher that will allow me to create renpy programs by myself, once I learn the tutorial.

Curiously enough, when I repeat the sequence of commands in the terminal the same error still appears, and when I type “renpy”, it says that “could not import pygame_sdl2” and end doing nothing. It doesn’t matter to me, because I got what I wanted already and so I close this question.

Note: I am not renpy nor Ubuntu specialist, just a user, so your situation might be different as mine, but I gave some details for developers.